# Iterating over types in a variadic template

Tags: c++

I have a member function that is templated with a variadic template. The member function wants to push to a container somewhere some information about the types in the variadic template, such as `typeid(T)` and `sizeof(T)`.

The member function should also take in a variable amount of parameters, with each parameter's type being what is specified in the variadic template. Any parameter not explicitly defined should default to a default construction of the type.

Basically this, but bar is somehow a variadic template and that code repeats for all of the types in the variadic template.

```
class foo {
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::size_t> typeinfo;

public:
    template<typename T>
    void bar(T myType = T()) {
        typeinfo.insert({ typeid(T), sizeof(T) });
        
        // do stuff with myType ...
    }
};

foo myfoo;
myfoo.bar<int, double>(); // myType<int> = 0, myType<double> = 0.0;
myfoo.bar<char, float>('a'); // myType<char> = 'a', myType<float> = 0.0f;
myfoo.bar<double, char>(32.4, 'b'); // myType<double> = 32.4, myType<char> = 'b'
```

Comment: Although this is not something that's very complicated to implement, all the alarm bells go off every time I see someone asking a question that involves `typeid()`. It ultimately turns out to be an attempt, somehow, to defeat C++'s type-safety. This always ends in tears. Can you explain the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one that involves using `typeid()` in this manner, with a variadic template; but the problem to which you believe the solution is to use `typeid()` in this manner, with a variadic template. It's almost a certainty that a better solution exists.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: It most certainly is a work-around for the type safety system. I have vector of contiguous blocks of bytes to store different types in. I'm creating a sort of interface where I call something like `byteManager.createNewBlocks<all, my, types>(All, My, Values);` and it would make a new block of bytes of a certain size to hold a given number of the given type, and assign the value to all the instances of the type now in that array. It's bad. It's horrible. But I don't know how to do it any better. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: How do I convert bar's `template<typename T>` into `template<typename... Ts>` and have the bar member function work as is, but basically repeat this function for every type specified by the variadic template @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: Again, that doesn't sound like the real problem. The real problem is the "sort of interface" in the first place. There should be a way to do this in a type-safe manner, leaving it to the C++ library to handle type-erasure, involving typeids, correctly. For a bounded list of types, a `std::variant`-based solution should work. For an unknown list of types, a `std::any`-based solution should work. There's almost never any need to deal with `typeid` directly, that always ends in tears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter pack cannot have default argument

so

```
template<typename... Ts>
void bar(Ts... = Ts()...) // ill-formed
```

What you can do is using 2 parameter-packs

```
class foo {
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::size_t> typeinfo;

public:
    // Us... is non deducible
    template<typename... Us, typename... Ts>
    void bar(Ts... /*args*/) {
        (typeinfo.insert({ typeid(Us), sizeof(Us) }), ...);
        // You might have to check that Ts... start Us...
        // use end of Us... for args...
    }
};

void test()
{
    foo myfoo;
    myfoo.bar<int, double>(); // Us=[int, double], Ts=[]
    myfoo.bar<char, float>('a'); // Us =[char, float], Ts = [char];
    myfoo.bar<double, char>(32.4, 'b'); // Us=[double, char], Ts=[double, int]
    myfoo.bar<char>(4.2f); // Us =[char], Ts = [float] !!!
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6f7a5eb36c10707)

To create a tuple with initial part from `Us`, and remaining defaulted, you might do

```
template <typename T, std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
T get_or_default(Tuple&& tuple)
{
    if constexpr (I < std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>) {
        return std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
    } else {
        return T{};
    }
}

template<typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is,  typename Tuple>
std::tuple<Ts...>
make_partial_tuple_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&& tuple)
{
    return {get_or_default<Ts, Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...};
}

template<typename... Ts, typename... Us>
std::tuple<Ts...> make_partial_tuple(Us&&... args)
{
    return make_partial_tuple_impl<Ts...>(
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{},
        std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Us>(args)...));
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a4579b5b395722b)

Comment: You also could omit the parameters of `bar()` if you don't use them (like in the example).

Comment: @JakobStark: I suspect OP wants to use parameter.

Comment: The idea behind the default constructor is that Ts would be the same size as Us, and if Us is larger than Ts, Ts would be filled up with the default values for the types of Us. Is there a way to have that sort of functionality?

Comment: @spitconsumer: Added the missing part.